# Python Serial Read 3 byte hex and print as an array on one line

Tags: python, hex, pyserial

I have a simple program that is receiving hex data via serial port it is in 6 bytes. When I print it out it prints on separate lines.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM15')
print(ser.name)
while True:
    in_hex = ser.read().hex()
    print(in_hex)

Output:
aa    
40
16
44
00
56
```

How can I make this on one line ? For Example {aa, 40 16, aa, 00, 56} I have tried bytearray, tried setting array size. Everything I try does not work.

Can I set the string length somehow?

After This I want to verify the first element. if that is true then verify the following elements match.
any suggestions would be great
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Make in_hex into an array and append each element to the array.

Then you can print in_hex and it will print all the numbers on the same line, as you intended.